# Model saved when called from a class but not from another - save() not working

Tags: magento

I am trying to enhance an existing payment module (Paybox) and it's been hours I have been stuck on this headbreaking scenario : even if I successfully can save a model to the DB from the original model, I cannot call / save it from another class / model.

**The original model :**

```
class Quadra_Paybox_Model_Saved extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function saveCardInformation() {

        $data['customer_id'] = 12;
        $data['porteur'] = 'porteur';
        $data['dateval'] = 'dateval';
        $data['cvv'] = 'cvv';
        $data['numtrans'] = 'numtrans';
        $data['numappel'] = 'numappel';

        $this->setData($data);
        $this->save();

        return $this;       
    }
}
```

Of course, there is the resource model attached to it and working :

```
class Quadra_Paybox_Model_Mysql4_Saved extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {

    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('paybox/saved', 'id');
    }
}
```

**The "calling" model :**

```
class Quadra_Paybox_Model_Direct extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc
{
    public function saveCardInformationAlias() {
        Mage::getModel('paybox/saved')->saveCardInformation();      
    }

    public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {       
        $this->saveCardInformationAlias();  
        die('ok');
    }
}
```

Please note that this model extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc. When I try to make it extend Mage_Core_Model_Abstract I get this error which may be a clue that I cannot use / understand :

```
Error: Invalid method Quadra_Paybox_Model_Direct::prepareSave(Array ( ) )
```

**The file that I use for testing :**

I've created a CMS page (identifier = testmodule) embedding a phtml template (template/testmodule.phtml). I call this by navigating to www.mydomain.com/testmodule
Here is the code of this template :

```
<?php
Mage::getModel('paybox/direct')->saveCardInformationAlias();
?>
```

---

Now comes the tricky part.
Step by step scenario :

**Step 1-** Navigate to www.mydomain.com/testmodule. Everyhting flows, the DB is correctly updated :

[image: step1]

---

**Step 2-** Place an order on the front office which goes thru the capture() method of the "calling" model Quadra_Paybox_Model_Direct :

Proof that the process goes "well" : I get the "ok" returned by the `die('ok');`

but the DB is not updated! It still shows :

[image: step2]

---

**Step 3-** Navigate again to www.mydomain.com/testmodule... and surprise, a new row is here but with a jump in the ID (auto_increment) :

[image: step3]

---

So this is where I need your great help :

- why isn't my model saving the data at step 2 ?
- why is there a jump in the ID field meaning that somehow a request / insert has been sent to the DB ?

I hope those explanations are clear and will give you enough data to share your clues.

---

Edit : I've also tried via direct core/write queries and also via dispatching an event that I observe in a 100% independant module. Same conclusion in both case : calling the method on its own works but calling it in the workflow doesn't... Still no save and a jump in ID in the DB.

Comment: Are you loading the data into the paybox/saved model at any stage? It doesn't look as though your are, which would explain the issue (and depending on the way the model works - the jump in id)

Comment: No, I'm not loading any data in the model prior to saving it. This way (the Magento way), a new entry is added in the DB on model save. Moreover, I think that if data load was mandatory, any of the 3 steps I explained would save info in the DB. Indeed, in any of those 3 steps data is loaded in the model. Thanks for your thoughts though!

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the bit where the data is being set...
The only thing I can suggest is to turn on mysql logging and see if the INSERT is being called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database's autoincrement is incrementing but apparently without saving then it must be an aborted transaction. Try removing the `die()` from your code to see if it progresses further, you can still use `Mage::log()` for outputting.

There are several transactions used throughout the Sales module, [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com/) for "core/resource_transaction" to see some of them. Existing events don't pass transaction objects around which would be really helpful, so there may not be a way of adding your object to one of those. Also models employ a transaction during their own save which means other models cannot be saved within them, MySQL does not support nested transactions.

Your eventual solution may have to be moving the save to another part of the process. Or perhaps you can leverage the fields on a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment` since that is close to what you are storing and is correctly saved as part of the order transaction.

Comment: That was it! When I asked my question, the capture() method was being debugged thus the transaction wasn't successful causing @rollback in mySQL. This rollback left the ID auto_increment still incremented. I then debugged the whole capture method() and it worked like a charm. I owe you a ticker + 1. There we go. Thanks again.